# How to find out any red line present in a scanned pdf , where somebody may strikes on some text or just a simple line on pdf using Python or vb.net

Tags: python, pdf, uicolor

I need to find out any red lines present in a scanned  pdf file some thing like some body put a red line  on pdf  using Python or vb.net

we can ignore images and texts and just need to find out any red lines present in scanned pdf using python or vb.net

Comment: Please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. It may be helpful to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I need to find out any red  line present in a  scanned pdf document when doing quality check  for a  opportunity in salesforce  i tried below code but for all pdf's the below code is showing red color is preset in pdf .

Comment: below code always shows red color = true  though red  line not present in a scanned pdf   how to fix this                                      
 import fitz  # PyMuPDF
def is_red_color(color):
    r, g, b = color
    return r > g and r > b

def extract_font_color_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    font_color = (255, 0, 0) 
    return font_color
  def check_red_color_in_pdf(pdf_path):
    font_color = extract_font_color_from_pdf(pdf_path)
    red_present = is_red_color(font_color)
    return red_present
pdf_path = "mypdf.pdf"
red_present = check_red_color_in_pdf(pdf_path)
print(red_present)

Comment: If you do not check the single pixels of the page's underlying image, there is no hope at all. No OCR engine I have ever come across returns **_colors_**. And very few even return lines at all. So short answer: forget that idea.

Comment: @PaavakV Could you please [edit] your question to add information. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice. Editing your question ensures that the additional information doesn't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees it.